# yguard keep can't specify more than 1 class element

Tags: yguard

After keep for public api, I can't include classes belonging to a sub package, see com.example.protocol.* below

```
<keep>
   <class classes="protected"
       methods="protected"
       fields="protected">
      </class>

     <!------------------- this part doesn't work ----------------------------->
      <class>
          <patternset>
              <include name="com.example.protocol.*"/>
          </patternset>
      </class>
</keep>
```

Tried above pom.xml but resulting class is still obfuscated

Answer (score 0):

From the [yGuard documentation](https://yworks.github.io/yGuard/task_documentation.html#the-class-element):

> If [...] the class element contains no nested patternset, a class element matches all class names.

This means the classes that match the patternset from the second `class` element **also** match the first `class` element. And that means your configuration contains contradictory directives. In such a case, there is no defined behavior for yGuard's `keep` element.

You need to exclude the classes you want to match in the second `class` element from the set that is matched in the first `class` element:

```
<keep>
  <class classes="protected" methods="protected" fields="protected">
    <patternset>
      <include name="**"/>
      <exclude name="com.example.protocol.*"/>
    </patternset>
  </class>
  <class>
    <patternset>
      <include name="com.example.protocol.*"/>
    </patternset>
  </class>
</keep>
```